# How can I add a break within two values in php?

Tags: php, html, mysql, tags

I got this code

```
       $title = new FullName($reservation->Title, $reservation->Description)
```

which shows the values Title and Description inside a box, but it does so directly following each other. When the box is too small it does a line break, but only at the exact point of the end of the box. so how can i force a line break between $reservation->Title and $reservation->Description ?

Here is the Full Name Class

```
        class FullName
        {
/**
 * @var string
 */
private $fullName;

public function __construct($firstName, $lastName)
{
    $formatter = Configuration::Instance()->GetKey(ConfigKeys::NAME_FORMAT);
    if (empty($formatter))
    {
        $this->fullName = "$firstName $lastName";
    }
    else
    {
        $this->fullName = str_replace('{first}', $firstName, $formatter);
        $this->fullName = str_replace('{last}', $lastName, $this->fullName);
    }
}

public function __toString()
{
    return $this->fullName;
}
```

}

Comment: i dont understand; pls explain more, and a quick example

Comment: please post the FullName class

Comment: Title outputs a phrase and Description outputs a phrase. Title= This is the Title and Description= This is the Description. Right now the line break is here: This is the Title and Description This is [line break] the Description, but I want it here This is the Title [line break] This is the Description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a good way without proper explanation, but a Quick solution

Replace

```
$title = new FullName($reservation->Title, $reservation->Description)
```

with

```
   $t = $reservation->Title . "<br />";
   $d = $reservation->Description;
   $title = new FullName($t, $d);
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML line break can be inserted as:

```
$this->fullName = $firstName . '<br />' . $lastName
```

or with generic (non-HTML) new-line character:

```
$this->fullName = $firstName . "\n" . $lastName
```

It is important to use double quotes in last case (").

Answer (score 0):

See the link for working example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/qS7nNv

You can add a third parameter to the class.

```
class FullName
{
/**
 * @var string
 */
private $fullName;

public function __construct($firstName, $lastName, $delimiter = null)
{
    $formatter = Configuration::Instance()->GetKey(ConfigKeys::NAME_FORMAT);
    if (empty($formatter))
    {
      if($delimiter) {
        $this->fullName = "$firstName $delimiter $lastName";
      } else {
        $this->fullName = "$firstName $lastName";
      }
    }
    else
    {
        $this->fullName = str_replace('{first}', $firstName, $formatter);
        $this->fullName = str_replace('{last}', $lastName, $this->fullName);
    }
}

public function __toString()
{
    return $this->fullName;
}
 }
```

then add the delimiter:

```
$title = new FullName($reservation->Title, $reservation->Description, "<br />");
```